# No converter found capable of converting from type [java.time.LocalDateTime] to type [java.util.Date]

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, datetime

I am using MongoDBTempalate with Springboot and trying to aggregate data basis LocalDateTime in which I am getting this error : org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.time.LocalDateTime] to type [java.util.Date]

I tried adding a custom convertor but it did not help, the code I added is :

```
`@Bean
    public MongoCustomConversions customConversions(){
        List<Converter<?,?>> converters = new ArrayList<>();
        converters.add(DateToLocalDateTimeConverter.INSTANCE);
        converters.add( LocalDateTimeToDateConverter.INSTANCE);
        return new MongoCustomConversions(converters);
    }

    enum DateToLocalDateTimeConverter implements Converter<Date, LocalDateTime> {

        INSTANCE;

        @Override
        public LocalDateTime convert(Date source) {
            return ofInstant(source.toInstant(), systemDefault());
        }
    }

    enum LocalDateTimeToDateConverter implements Converter<LocalDateTime, Date> {

        INSTANCE;

        @Override
        public Date convert(LocalDateTime source) {
            return Date.from(source.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC));
        }
    }`
```

Can someone tell me where have I gone wrong in creating the convertor, or is there some alternative apart from changing the LocalDateTime to Date in the code, as the occurance are very huge and refactoring might take a lot of time and effort

Comment: Make sure you're not importing `java.sql.Date`.

Comment: Do you actually use the `java.util.Date` class somewhere? Normally, you don't need a converter to handle `java.time.LocalDateTime` in a specific way with Spring and Mongo

Comment: As an aside your conversion does not seem to be reversible. You are using different time zones in the two converters, so a full roundtrip will give you a different result from what you started with.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this annotation on your entity or DTO, it will automatically format the date.

@Document(collection = "sample")
public class Foo{

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm', locale = "en-PH")
private Date createdAt;

}

Comment: why does it need a json format for conversion from localdate to date?